# The constructor ClassCountry(String, String, String, int) is undefined

Tags: java, string

Eclipse keeps saying the constructor is undefined - what's wrong here? I have checked everything.

```
package exerciseOne;

public class TestCountryClass {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        ClassCountry oCon1 = new ClassCountry("Iceland", "Icelandic", "króna", 400000);         

        System.out.printf("%s %s %d%n", oCon1.getCountryName(),
                                        oCon1.getCountryLanguage(),
                                        oCon1.getCountryCurrency(),
                                        oCon1.getCountryPopulation());

    }

}
```

Here is the code for the Class, I have checked multiple times but Eclipse kept returning the same error message. I hope you guys are able to find the issue here; any help is appreciated:

```
package exerciseOne;

public class ClassCountry {

    private String countryName;
    private String countryLanguage;
    private String countryCurrency;
    private int countryPopulation;

    public void classCountry(String countryName, String countryLanguage, String countryCurrency, int countryPopulation)
    {
        this.countryName = countryName;
        this.countryLanguage = countryLanguage;
        this.countryCurrency = countryCurrency;
        this.countryPopulation = countryPopulation;

    }

    public void setCountryName(String countryName)
    {
        this.countryName = countryName;
    }
    public String getCountryName()
    {
        return countryName;
    }
    public void setCountryLanguage(String countryLanguage)
    {
        this.countryLanguage = countryLanguage;
    }
    public String getCountryLanguage()
    {
        return countryLanguage;
    }
    public void setCountryPopulation(int countryPopulation)
    {
        this.countryPopulation = countryPopulation;
    }
    public int getCountryPopulation()
    {
        return countryPopulation;
    }

    public void setCountryCurrency(String countryCurrency)
    {
        this.countryCurrency = countryCurrency;
    }
    public String getCountryCurrency()
    {
        return countryCurrency;
    }

}
```

Comment: You don't have a matching constructor. Post the code for class `ClassCountry`.

Comment: Post your constructor

Comment: Check the constructors in your ClassCountry class. If there is such a constructor, you may have forgotten to save the file, or to build the project, but the most likely issue is that this constructor doesn't exist

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
public void classCountry(String countryName, String countryLanguage, String countryCurrency, int countryPopulation)
{
    this.countryName = countryName;
    this.countryLanguage = countryLanguage;
    this.countryCurrency = countryCurrency;
    this.countryPopulation = countryPopulation;

}
```

Here is your problem. You've added this as constructor, but this is not a constructor. This is a method with returntype void.

Change the above to:

```
public ClassCountry(String countryName, String countryLanguage, String countryCurrency, int countryPopulation)
{
    this.countryName = countryName;
    this.countryLanguage = countryLanguage;
    this.countryCurrency = countryCurrency;
    this.countryPopulation = countryPopulation;

}
```

For more information about constructors, you can check this [Oracle tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/constructors.html).

Comment: Thanks Everyone, i found the solution, it should look like this:

Comment: public ClassCountry(String countryName, String countryLanguage, String countryCurrency, int countryPopulation)

Answer (score 4):

Your "constructor" is not a constructor because it is a method.

Change `classCountry` to `ClassCountry` and remove the void.

```
public ClassCountry(...
```

Answer (score 0):

```
package com.String;

public class StackOverFlow {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    ClassCountry oCon1 = new ClassCountry("Iceland", "Icelandic", "króna", 400000);         

    System.out.printf("%s %s %s %d", oCon1.getCountryName(),
                                    oCon1.getCountryLanguage(),
                                    oCon1.getCountryCurrency(),
                                    oCon1.getCountryPopulation());

}



private static class ClassCountry{

    private String countryName;
    private String countryLanguage;
    private String countryCurrency;
    private int countryPopulation;

    public ClassCountry(String countryName, String countryLanguage, String countryCurrency, int countryPopulation) {
        super();
        this.countryName = countryName;
        this.countryLanguage = countryLanguage;
        this.countryCurrency = countryCurrency;
        this.countryPopulation = countryPopulation;
    }
    public String getCountryName() {
        return countryName;
    }
    public String getCountryLanguage() {
        return countryLanguage;
    }
    public String getCountryCurrency() {
        return countryCurrency;
    }
    public int getCountryPopulation() {
        return countryPopulation;
    }       

}
}
```

I guess this will help

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/arguments.html

Comment: no, it won't, since you have no idea what the ClassCountry code of the OP is supposed to be. Who says he can/may alter it?

Comment: @Sam edit the question so that it contains your ClassCountry code

Comment: @Sam use System.out.printf("%s %s %s %d",... instead of  System.out.printf("%s %s %d%n"....

Comment: @Stultuske we dont need the classcountry. look at the String Format

Comment: @ThamizhRoi yes, we do. trust me

Comment: @Sam check the String format brother. it should match. its working for me.

Comment: @ThamizhRoi read the error we are trying to solve. It is a "Constructor not found". It's not related to the String format

Comment: what string format worked for you? I thought mine matched (String, String, String, int)

Answer (score 0):

The cause for this error message is the following line:

```
public void classCountry(...
```

A constructor must not have a return value, so you have to remove `void`. Also the constructor has to match the class definition with regard to upper and lower case. So change the line to

```
public ClassCountry(...
```

and it will work.

Comment: No, it won't. Java is case sensitive. classCountry should be ClassCountry

Comment: @Stultuske You are right, thanks a lot. I corrected my answer.

Answer (score 0):

The Class name is : ClassCountry.
The Constructor name should be same like : public ClassCountry ().
However in your case the constructor that you think it should be, is not actually a constructor, rather it is considered as a simple method.

So correct the spelling of the constructor name, also remove the void part.

Answer (score -1):

You have a class called ClassCountry so your constructor must take the form

```
public ClassCountry(args) {}
```

Java is a case sensitive language so classCountry will not match the constructor and you also had a void in your constructor which creates a method with no return value rather than a constructor.